# Calling function on notification button click

Tags: java, android

I'm making a notification app, and want to trigger a function when notification button is clicked. I was able to open app when clicking on the button, but can't manage to get any console log by clicking it.

**Notification**

```java
public void displayNotification() {
   Log.i("NotificationService", "NotificationService test");
   Intent intent = new Intent(reactContext, com.uzskaite.MainActivity.class);
   // intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   // intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
   // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "textMessage");
   // intent.setType("text/plain");
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
   Uri uri = intent.getData();
   // Log.i("NotificationService", "URI "+uri.toString());
   Intent intents = new Intent("my.action.data");
   intents.putExtra("otp");
   sendBroadcast(intents);
   PendingIntent snoozePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.reactContext, 0, intents, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.reactContext, 0, intent, 0);
   String CHANNEL_ID = "notificationsChannel";
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.reactContext, CHANNEL_ID);
   builder.setSmallIcon(17301575);
   builder.setContentTitle("Notifiks");
   builder.setContentText("Narmal teksts");
   builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
   builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
   builder.setAutoCancel(false);
   builder.addAction(17301575, "Yes", snoozePendingIntent);
   builder.setOngoing(true);
   NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this.reactContext);
   notificationManager.notify(2, builder.build());
}
```

And there goes **BroadcastReceiver**

```java
package com.notifications;

import android.util.Log;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("NotificationService", "NotificationService test");
    String action = intent.getAction();

  }
}
```

The point where I'm stuck is `PendingIntent`. Can't manage to get it to `BroadcastReceiver`.

Manifest

```
  <receiver android:name=".ActionReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="my.action.data" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Comment: Did you register your broadcast receiver with an intent filer action: "my.action.data" ?

Comment: @easy_breezy I added manifest.

Comment: What do you mean with notification button. Do you want to listen on notification click or you want to add an action button to your notification?

Comment: @Gabriel14 I need to add action button to notification, and when i click it, i want to send data to api ( for now atleast figure out how to get console log when i click action button).

Comment: @Gabriel14 as u see, i added button with .addaction();, i have the button in notification, but whenever i click it, nothing happens.

Comment: try to change "0" in PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...) to some other value for example "123"

Comment: @easy_breezy didn't help.

Comment: Any tips or ideas about, whats wrong? :(